# Calc I Related Rates Question involving a Circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, relations

Two runners at the same point begin running in opposite directions along a
circular track of radius $100$m at a speed of $5$m/s. At what rate is the (shortest)
distance between them growing after $10$s?

i have done many related rates problems but none like this and have no idea where to even start any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I hope my answer helps!

Comment: @Infinity yes it helped me alot thanks for your help !

Comment: you're always welcome on Math SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I've answered this question before and I cannot comment because I'm new user hers

but Here's the answer

Let's assume they travel with constant velocity $v$, and Radius of circle be $r$

After time $t$ Arc length will be $vt$ 
$$l=vt=r\theta$$
and angle subtending that arc will be 
$$\theta=\frac{vt}{r}$$ now shortest distance between them will be $$x=2r\sin\theta$$

Now we have our relation
$$x=2r\sin\left(\frac{vt}{r}\right)$$
Now rate of change of shortest distance between them is
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2r\frac{v}{r}\cos\left(\frac{vt}{r}\right)=2v\cos\left(\frac{vt}{r}\right)$$
Now plug in values

Here's a rough diagram if it helps

[image]

**Note:**
In figure after time $t$ their respective positions are shown by $A$ and $A'$

$$x=AA'$$
$$r=BA=BA'$$
$$\angle ABO=\angle A'BO=\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, and $\theta$ at 10 seconds. Then, you can find a equation involving the distance, since you know the radius, and the angle $\theta$ between them, and thus can write a formula for the distance. Take the derivative with respect to $t$, and you should get your answer.