# Relate Rates with Circle

Tags: calculus

Two runners at the same point begin running in opposite directions along a
circular track of radius $100$m at a speed of $5$m/s. At what rate is the (shortest)
distance between them growing after $10$sec?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture of where they are at $10$ seconds and which way they are going? Do you see any symmetries in this problem that will help you? Any other things you have tried?

Comment: The question is very close to [this recent question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006886/calc-i-related-rates-question-involving-a-circle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume they travel with constant velocity $v$, and Radius of circle be $r$

After time $t$ Arc length will be $vt$ 
$$l=vt=r\theta$$
and angle subtending that arc will be 
$$\theta=\frac{vt}{r}$$ now shortest distance between them will be $$x=2r\sin\theta$$

Now we have our relation
$$x=2r\sin\left(\frac{vt}{r}\right)$$
Now rate of change of shortest distance between them is
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2r\frac{v}{r}\cos\left(\frac{vt}{r}\right)=2v\cos\left(\frac{vt}{r}\right)$$
Now plug in values

Here's a rough diagram if it helps

[image]

**Note:**
In figure after time $t$ their respective positions are shown by $A$ and $A'$

$$x=AA'$$
$$r=BA=BA'$$
$$\angle ABO=\angle A'BO=\theta$$

Comment: Thank you, just a quick question about the solution. How did you get the "shortest distance formula"? (x=2rsin(vt/r))

Comment: @Byce Actually It's simple trigonometry Hypotaneous of triangle is R then I've to find perpendicular side.